# R generation of sequences from 2 columns data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have a `data.frame` composed by 2 columns in which the first one represents the starting number of a sequence and the second one is the ending number of the same sequence.

For each row, I want to generate a sequence as I just described.

Data:

```
structure(list(start = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30), 
end = c(7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34)), .Names = c("start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

> b
   start end
1      3   7
2      6  10
3      9  13
4     12  16
5     15  19
6     18  22
7     21  25
8     24  28
9     27  31
10    30  34
```

I thought that a simple

```
seq(b[,1],b[,2])
```

should work, but it's not.

The result I want is a list of sequences, thus in this case 10 lists (or another container). As example, the first sequence should be: 3,4,5,6,7. Others are the same as I shown.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I want the same output of the question you linked. I was not able to find that question by searching on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `Map`

```
Map(`:`, b$start, b$end)
```

If you need a matrix output

```
mapply(`:`, b$start, b$end)
```

Or

```
apply(b, 1, function(x) seq(x[1], x[2]))
```